# how to select all paths which have empty or only space type strings

Tags: jq

I have the following JSON

```json
{
   "key0" : null,
   "key"  : 1010,
   "key1" : "",
   "key2" : "  ",
   "key3" : {
    "key4" : "   ",
    "key5" : "test"
   }
}
```

I want to get all the paths of keys whose values are either empty string or string with only spaces

I am trying

```
path(..|select(. == ""))
```

But how to extend the above to regex like "^\s*"  which can check all values with empty string or string with only spaces.

Comment: That's not a valid JSON

Comment: hi i have corrected it

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strings` to filter for strings, and `test` to have regex test return a boolean. The regex itself has to be a JSON string, so use `\\` for escaping.

```bash
jq -c 'paths(strings | test("^\\s*$"))' input.json
```

```json
["key1"]
["key2"]
["key3","key4"]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Hz_Nzuu77qA)

Comment: Hi, now i have a task to replace all such empty strings or strings with only spaces with null. can i do that using jq

Comment: @Santhosh For that, you wouldn't need the paths. Just update while traversing. Using your approach with `..`: `(.. | strings | select(test("^\\s*$"))) = null` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/i0AUyW6e2Bl). Or using `walk`: `walk(select(strings | test("^\\s*$")) = null)` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/HuJGxPdED-l)

Comment: you are a saviour... thanks a lot.

Comment: where can we learn this about jq

Comment: @Santhosh [the manual](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/) is pretty good, give it a look, maybe search for keyword in the page when you're trying to solve something. The start is a bit dense but lower in goes into every operator with examples

Comment: @Santhosh I'd also recommend the [manual](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/). And then, there's also a [tutorial](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/tutorial/) and a [wiki](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/wiki).